# How can I register an expected memory leak for an Interface object

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe2

Is it possible to register an Interface with the `RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak` procedure?

I have a private field declared as:

```
FDragDropTarget: IDropTarget;
```

I then create an instance of this and attempt to Register a known memory leak for this object:

```
  FDragDropTarget := TDropTarget.Create(lcMain.Handle, FDragDrop);
  RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(FDragDropTarget);
```

However I get a compiler error stating that there is Incompatible types: 'Pointer' and 'IDropTarget'.  To me, my interface instance is a pointer anyway?

So can I do this?  It's being reported via the ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True statement I have in my .dpr file.

```
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

TDropTarget is my implementation of the IDropTarget interface:

```
  TDropTarget = class(TInterfacedObject, IDropTarget)
  ...
  end;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the interface that leaks, but the object implementing it. So I think that's the one that needs to be registered:

```
FDragDropTargetObj: TDropTarget;
FDragDropTarget: DropTarget;


FDragDropTargetObj := TDropTarget.Create(lcMain.Handle, FDragDrop); 
FDragDropTarget := FDragDropTargetObj;
RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(FDragDropTargetObj);
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of typecasting, but was not sure about the old "don't mix interface and object references", but given you and David both provided effectively the same solution it must be right!

Comment: Yes. You're right about not mixing... but in this case you don't. All you do is register an anonymous pointer to a chunk of memory, to let the memory manager check is that memory is released. It actually has nothing to do with either objects or interfaces. This is one of those exceptions they never tell you about. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the implementing object, rather than the interface, as the think that is leaked:

```
RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(FDragDropTarget as TObject);
```

The fact that this object leaks suggests that your reference counting is broken somehow. I'd probably look to fix the underlying problem rather than suppress it.

Comment: The field should have been declared `TDropTarget` for this to work. But then there wouldn't be a question..

Comment: @Sertac why would this not work? Interface can be cast to implementing object.

Comment: @sertac no worries. Still there must be something wrong for an interface to leak.

Comment: Yes, the memory leak should be fixed, but for now it's a minor concern and I was just interested in hiding the message for this particular scenario. Thanks

Comment: It's easy to find the cause of the leak. Your code is somehow taking an extra reference to the object which it never gives up. Reimplement `IInterface` on `TDropTarget` by using the same code as you find in `TInterfacedObject`'s implementation. Then set break points on `TDropTarget._AddRef` and `TDropTarget._Release`. This will reveal the cause of the extra reference being taken.